# Apex Test coverage for impersonation or login as user

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Is it possible to write a test class to mimic the impersonation ? Due to one of the salesforce release, impersonation has failed and salesforce support mentioned that the issue should have been caught if we have test class or coverage to impersonate the user .

Comment: That sounds ridiculous. Unit tests are not intended to test standard Salesforce mechanisms - we should be able to assume these work. Support are being... unsupportive.

Comment: Agree, thank you Phil